# Solve this problem without using trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry

The slender object at a distance of 100 meters we see at an angle $1^\circ$. How is him altitude? Solve this exercise without using trigonometric functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the small angle, we can assume that the object is a circle arc with angle $1°$. So, its length is $\frac{2\times 100\pi}{360}=1.7453$ which is very close to the answer $100\tan(1°)=1.7455$ which we get using trigonometric functions.